# Cannot find external module 'angular2/http'

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I used the latest angular.d.ts v2.0.0-alpha.31 and angular.dev.js v31. when i execute the tsc or compile my typescript code it says "Cannot find external module 'angular2/http'"

Comment: Resolve this issue please take a look at this.


https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3141

Answer (score 10):

The http module separated from angular.dev.js. Its in the http.dev.js now.

Comment: maybe superfluously: you need to add BOTH angular.dev.js and http.dev.js to your index.html. Took me some time to understand the answer :)